# Regex pattern for number or three letters

Tags: regex

I need to sort a table field with different kind of values:

- number from 0 to 999+
- group of three letters like AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD, etc.

[StupidTable.js](https://github.com/joequery/Stupid-Table-Plugin#creating-your-own-data-types) enables me to add a custom alphanumeric data type, but i'm not able to define the regex pattern.

I tried this code:

```
$("table").stupidtable({
  "alphanum":function(a,b){

       console.log(a,b)

       var pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$";
       var re = new RegExp(pattern);

       var aNum = re.exec(a).slice(1);
       var bNum = re.exec(b).slice(1);

       return parseInt(aNum,10) - parseInt(bNum,10);
 }
})
```

but it doesnt work. You can check the issue on this page clicking on "nr" tab: [Test](http://dev.mzz.design/a2bc/works/all)

Comment: What's your question? What have you already tried and what didn't work? Please [edit] to clarify. Check out [ask] for more advice.

Comment: Hi Giuliano, it seems clear from your question you need a regular expression pattern that matches the examples you provided. I have attempted to answer your question below. Please also review the info @wjandrea provided as it will help you with asking better questions in the future. Stack Overflow members generally prefer it when users take a moment to paste the code they have tried, with some detail into what they want, and what the problem is they are having. Good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

`const regexPattern = /^[\d\w]{3}/gm;`

This pattern allows you to capture a string if it contains only a 3 digit number or a 3 letter code. If you want to capture 0 and not 000, you will need to change {3} with {1,3}, but this will also capture A instead of AAA.

You might also consider normalizing your data in some ways, e.g. converting A to AAA and 0 to 000. This could be helpful for a number of reasons assuming your variable type is a string and not actually a number type. Does that make sense?

You can see how I've created this pattern at the link below, and try some tweaks to make it work well for you. I use this tool a lot and it will also generate some code for you in different languages. Good luck with your project, let me know how it goes.

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/WidFQv/1)

Comment: Your regex matches `A_3` or `1_2` or  `x2_ljhgf*ù$-#~.......` and many other that shouldn't be matched.